# Dropezone MVC5 Add extra parameter on Upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to upload files to my server without any issues, i would like to add extra parameters such a meta data.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Code Below and just using controller in normal fashion

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
      <div class="ibox-title">
        <h5>Select</h5>
        <div class="ibox-tools">
          <a class="collapse-link">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content">
        <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="@Url.Action(" FileUploadHandler ", "Controller ")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit your application</button>
        </form>
        <div>
          <div class="m text-right">test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> `

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      parallelUploads: 1,
      maxFiles: 1,
      maxFilesize: 2000,
      paramName: "test,123",
      acceptedFiles: ".zip",

      // Dropzone settings
      init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          myDropzone.processQueue();

          //Get All information to submit to server
          var appName = "";
          var typeOfApp = 1;
          var commandLine = "";
          var osType = 1;


        });

        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
          data.append("filetype", "avataruploadtype");
        });

      }
    }

  });
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up, you're just submitting the form, so one easy approach is to just add inputs (or hidden fields) to the form and handle the multipart form data on the server.

See here for detail:
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: Apologies Colin can you be more specific? im not sure where i would need to post in the javascript? would i just add a paraname and value, and just replicate that on the controller?

Comment: I added a link that should demonstrate the approach.